# Set default selected label in select item after form submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I want to do this:
`printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', $type['value'], ($type['value'] == $_GET['resource_type']? 'selected': ''), $type['label']);`

On this form layout:

```html
<div class="m-all t-1of4 d-1of4 cf search-field">
    <select name="resource_cat">
        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Category</option>
        <?php foreach($category_query as $cat){
            printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $cat->slug, $cat->name);
        } ?>
    </select>
    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
</div>
```

Basically, I just want the category label (name) to remain set after form submit if it was selected. I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around the logic for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is an if condition,

```
($type['value'] == $_GET['resource_type']? 'selected': '')
```

It is similar (in the case of printf) to

```
if($type['value'] == $_GET['resource_type']) {
    echo "selected";
} else {
    echo "";
}
```

Basically, when the value in resource_type request argument is the same value as $type['value'] == $_GET['resource_type'], the html will have selected:

```
<option value="somevalue" selected>somedata</option>
```

Comment: Thank you. A small break helped, I guess I was exhausted. You solution is good but I went with: 

``printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', $cat->slug, ($cat->slug == $_GET['resource_cat']? 'selected': ''), $cat->name);``

Comment: I thought you wanted an explanation